# How to find every combination of a binary 16 digit number

Tags: vb.net

I have 16 different options in my program and i have a 16 character variable which is filled with 1's or 0's depending on the options that are selected (0000000000000000 means nothing is selected, 0010101010000101 means options 3,5,7,9,14 and 16 are selected, 1111111111111111 means everything is selected.)

When i run my program, the code looks (using an if statement) for a 1 in the designated character of the 16 digit number and if there is one there then it runs the code for that option, otherwise it skips it..

e.g option 3 looks too see if the 3rd character (0010000000000000) is a 1 and if it is it runs the code.

Now what i am trying to do is generate a list of every different combination that is possible so I can create an option for it to just loop through and run every possible option:

0000000000000001
0000000000000010
0000000000000011
...
1111111111111100
1111111111111110
1111111111111111

I have tried this but i think it may take a couple of years to run jaja:

```
    Dim binString As String
```

Dim binNUM As Decimal = "0.0000000000000001"

```
    Do Until binNUM = 0.11111111111111111
        binString = binNUM.ToString
        If binString.Contains(1) Then
            If binString.Contains(2) Or binString.Contains(3) Or binString.Contains(4) Or binString.Contains(5) Or binString.Contains(6) Or binString.Contains(7) Or binString.Contains(8) Or binString.Contains(9) Then

            Else
                Debug.Print(binNUM)
            End If
        End If

        binNUM = binNUM + 0.0000000000000001
```

After the code above is complete i would then take the output list and remove any instances of "0." and then any lines which had fewer than 16 chararcters (because the final character would be a 0 and not show) I would add a 0 until there was 16 characters. I know this bit might be stupid but its as far a ive got

Is there a faster way I can I generate a list like this in VB.net?

Comment: Would this code even compile? What are you trying to do with the Contains(2)... code because there's no valid overload that takes an integer as an argument. On another note, it appears you have 16 options (not the binary equivalent of 16 1's) so couldn't you just loop through the string using a fore loop and do a select...case based on the iterator value when a 1 is found and perform the option?

Comment: Well its running and it is working but now its getting to the 8th digit and is taking forever. <br/>What this code is doing is starting at 0.0000000000000001 adding on the same value and then looping until the value is 0.1111111111111111. The contains part basically looks to see if the current number has anything other than a 1 or a 0 if if it does then it doesnt debug.print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the list by using [`Convert.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_System_Int32_) as follows:

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

For i As Integer = 0 To 65535
    sb.AppendLine(Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(16, "0"c))
Next

Debug.Print(sb.ToString())
```

BTW: This should finish in under one second, depending on your system ;-)

Comment: It works perfectly and runs in about 1 second haha. Thank you very much, haven't got a clue how it works but I will do some reading up.

Comment: @HitmanHeathcote it displays the value in base 2 (binary) instead of base 10.

Comment: I am dying to know, now that you have your 65,000 strings, what are you going to do with them?

Comment: @Mary basically my program has 16 different features and each feature has its own mathematical equation which gives me an output. When i put these outputs together using a final equation it will give me a value. What i plan on doing is running this with every possible combination to see which stats effect the final outcome. Kinda hard for me to explain but I've been researching this project for a year and have run basic tests but the only way for me to conclude is to run every possible combination to produce results. In the end it might be a waste of time haha

Answer (score 0):

Create an `enum` with `FlagAttributes`, which allows you to do the key functions you list. Here is an example of setting it up in a small project I am working on:

```
<FlagsAttribute>
Public Enum MyFlags As Integer
    None = 0
    One = 1
    Two = 2
    Three = 4
    Four = 8
    Five = 16
    Recon = 32
    Saboteur = 64
    Mine = 128
    Headquarters = 256
End Enum
```

e.g.

```
Dim temp as MyFlags
Dim doesIt as Boolean
temp = MyFlags.One
doesIt = temp.HasFlag(MyFlags.Two)
temp = temp OR MyFlags.Three
'etc.
```

The real advantage is how it prints out, if you want something other than 0, 1 and is much more human friendly.